# how to deploy laravel with iis manager

Tags: php, laravel, iis, deployment

how to run laravel with IIS manager? I have followed the tutorial on google about this but I got something like this when I finished setting please help me

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS1ph.png)

my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: From your screen, it is not rendering the laravel page. Please check (1) whether your IIS is currently supporting PHP; (2), whether the web.config is enabled /working and whether `URL Rewrite` (for IIS) is required to be installed in your server

Comment: I have installed url rewrite

Answer (score 1):

solve i forgot to add php extension in iis manager after i added and set the web config correctly now it can be accessed thanks stackoverflow friends